# How to reset python path to /usr/bin/python?

Tags: python

I was following certain instructions to install a package and ended up installing another version of python and creating symbolic links (the names I can't recall). Now when I hit python from terminal,  it is pointing to `/usr/local/python2.7/bin/python2.7`. I need to reset the default python to `/usr/bin/python`. How to do that?

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python /etc/python2.7 /etc/python /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/bin/X11/python2.7-config /usr/bin/X11/python2.7 /usr/bin/X11/python /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
$ 
$ python
bash: /usr/local/python2.7/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory
$ 
$ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2014, 19:10:20) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: What does "echo $PATH" say?

Answer (score 6):

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/python
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The OP asks `I need to reset the default python to /usr/bin/python. How to do that?`. I am pretty sure I answered that question.

Answer (score -1):

try to update the `$PATH` again in .bashrc (even if its defined in `$PATH`) 
That way the order of the PATH will be changed indirectly and first /usr/bin/ is chosen only then it will go to /usr/local/bin

```
PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: This issue seems to be a broken symlink, which this won't fix. Also what you're saying is not very clear.