# How to set Python back to the original version

Tags: package-management, python

I made my Python default version Python 3 in Ubuntu a few months ago but I don't know how I did it. Now I am trying to install pygame and it's throwing many errors. I feel that it's because my default Python is changed. I want to restore the original situation from before I made the changes.

I am new to Linux as well as Python so please let me know if you need any other information.

**Updated** `ls -l /usr/bin | grep python`

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root        1824 Feb  10 16:51 activate-global-python-argcomplete3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          26 Mei  18 17:10 dh_pypy -> ../share/dh-python/dh_pypy
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root        1056 Dis  10  2015 dh_python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          29 Mei  18 17:10 dh_python3 -> ../share/dh-python/dh_python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          23 Jul   3 03:05 pdb2.7 -> ../lib/python2.7/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          23 Jul   7 17:17 pdb3.5 -> ../lib/python3.5/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          31 Jun  28 11:01 py3versions -> ../share/python3/py3versions.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          26 Mei  18 17:10 pybuild -> ../share/dh-python/pybuild
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          16 Jul  18 20:49 python -> /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root           9 Jun  28 11:01 python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root     3546104 Jul   3 03:05 python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          33 Jul   3 03:05 python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          16 Dis  10  2015 python2-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root         319 Feb  24 22:53 python2-jsonschema
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root         151 Nov  23  2015 python2-pbr
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root           9 Jun  28 11:01 python3 -> python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root   root     4456272 Jul   7 17:17 python3.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          33 Jul   7 17:17 python3.5-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.5-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root   root     4456272 Jul   7 17:17 python3.5m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          34 Jul   7 17:17 python3.5m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.5m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          16 Mac  23 19:00 python3-config -> python3.5-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          10 Jun  28 11:01 python3m -> python3.5m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          17 Mac  23 19:00 python3m-config -> python3.5m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root        2553 Feb  10 16:51 python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          16 Dis  10  2015 python-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          29 Jun  28 11:01 pyversions -> ../share/python/pyversions.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root        1289 Feb  10 16:51 register-python-argcomplete3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root        2909 Jul   3 03:02 x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          34 Jul   7 17:17 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.5-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.5m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root        3185 Jul   7 17:14 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.5m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          33 Mac  23 19:00 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.5-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          34 Mac  23 19:00 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.5m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          33 Dis  10  2015 x86_64-linux-gnu-python-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
```

Comment: can't you reverse your original procedure? what did you do?

Comment: I actually do not remember how i did that because i was following various tutorials last month.

Comment: Now `python --version` this shows me `Python 3.5.2`

Comment: See this to reset link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/637848/how-to-reset-python-path-to-usr-bin-python If you want to see all the links: `ls -l /usr/bin/python*
`

Comment: ok... presumably you just changed where the symlink `/usr/bin/python` points to. Just to be sure we get it right, could you please do `ls -l /usr/bin | grep python` and add the output to your post?

Comment: @Zanna i pasted result above in updated part

Comment: now i did second blunder. There was a answer at askubuntu that to remove sym link you have to do rm /path/to/directory. I did `rm /usr/bin/python` and now when i type python --version it shows no python found

Comment: Note that you can install pygame for 3.5.2 - simply download the correct `.whl` file for your version [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) and use `pip` to install the `.whl` file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system's default version is the one pointed to by the symlink `/usr/bin/python`. In 16.04 this should be `python2.7` but you have changed it (as you discovered, this is a bad idea as many programs in Ubuntu use Python and will not work if they find the wrong version), and it is pointing to `/usr/bin/python3` which is a symlink pointing to `/usr/bin/python3.5`

Remove the symlink you changed (you can't just overwrite it in one step):

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
```

and make a new symlink with the same name to the correct Python version (that it originally pointed to). In your case this is `python2.7` so:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

now `python --version` will give you `Python 2.7.12` (or 2.7.[some number] depending on what minor version is installed)

Comment: great solution...Thanks