# Error when building tesseract from source

Tags: compiling, make, tesseract

I've hit an error trying to build tesseract. From the log output, my suspicion is that there is some python2 code causing an issue. My system python is 3.7. Not sure how to resolve, any tips appreciated.

Environment: Ubuntu 16.4 lts

Steps to reproduce:
(working directory is tessearact cloned git repo)

```
make clean
git pull
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-debug
make
```

relevant part of traceback:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/neil/Documents/tesseract/tesseract/doc'
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - combine_lang_model.1.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'combine_lang_model.1' failed
make[2]: [combine_lang_model.1] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - combine_tessdata.1.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'combine_tessdata.1' failed
make[2]: [combine_tessdata.1] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - dawg2wordlist.1.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'dawg2wordlist.1' failed
make[2]: [dawg2wordlist.1] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - lstmeval.1.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'lstmeval.1' failed
make[2]: [lstmeval.1] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - lstmtraining.1.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'lstmtraining.1' failed
make[2]: [lstmtraining.1] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - merge_unicharsets.1.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'merge_unicharsets.1' failed
make[2]: [merge_unicharsets.1] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - set_unicharset_properties.1.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'set_unicharset_properties.1' failed
make[2]: [set_unicharset_properties.1] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - tesseract.1.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'tesseract.1' failed
make[2]: [tesseract.1] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - text2image.1.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'text2image.1' failed
make[2]: [text2image.1] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - unicharambigs.5.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'unicharambigs.5' failed
make[2]: [unicharambigs.5] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - unicharset_extractor.1.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'unicharset_extractor.1' failed
make[2]: [unicharset_extractor.1] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - wordlist2dawg.1.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'wordlist2dawg.1' failed
make[2]: [wordlist2dawg.1] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - ambiguous_words.1.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'ambiguous_words.1' failed
make[2]: [ambiguous_words.1] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - classifier_tester.1.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'classifier_tester.1' failed
make[2]: [classifier_tester.1] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - cntraining.1.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'cntraining.1' failed
make[2]: [cntraining.1] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - mftraining.1.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'mftraining.1' failed
make[2]: [mftraining.1] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - shapeclustering.1.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'shapeclustering.1' failed
make[2]: [shapeclustering.1] Error 6 (ignored)
asciidoc -b docbook -d manpage -o - unicharset.5.asc | \
xsltproc --nonet http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl -
  File "/usr/bin/asciidoc", line 101
    except KeyError, k: raise AttributeError, k
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'unicharset.5' failed
make[2]: [unicharset.5] Error 6 (ignored)
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/neil/Documents/tesseract/tesseract/doc'
Making all in unittest
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/neil/Documents/tesseract/tesseract/unittest'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/neil/Documents/tesseract/tesseract/unittest'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/neil/Documents/tesseract/tesseract'
```

Comment: *My system python is 3.7*: Did you change default `python`? What is the output of `python -V`? Also, since Python3 is set to 3.5 by default, did you change that also? If yes, I'd strongly recommend you to revert back the edits asap since that might break some apps if not system.

Comment: neil~$ python -V
Python 3.7.4

yes, I did make some changes a while back. Didn't know it was an issue! Lemme try revert... tx

Comment: `python` should always invoke Python 2 as per [PEP #394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/#history-of-this-pep). Moreover, packages such as APT are bundled such that it works fine with Python 2/3 that is shipped with the release. Upgrading/downgrading them might cause serious problems and in the worst case, may break the system horribly which  can be near to impossible to recover. That said, unlike Windows, Python is an essential part of Linux systems. Messing them can cause some functions to limit and packages to misbehave.

Comment: learn something new everyday. Got the build to work by following instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/802134/how-to-set-python-back-to-the-original-version If you'd like, you can post above comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the code was originally written for Python 2.

```py
except KeyError, k
```

is a dead giveaway. You'll have to use Python 2 instead of Python 3 for the build recipes (I strongly don't recommend this.).

A better alternative is to find corresponding Python 3 code, or run `2to3` on the Python files (again, not guaranteed to work).

ETA: I noticed that the culprit was `asciidoc`. You'll have to use a [Python 3 version of asciidoc](https://github.com/asciidoc/asciidoc-py3).

Comment: How can I use Python 2 for the build recipie?

Comment: The `asciidoc` command was the culprit. You'll have to replace the `asciidoc` command with a Python 3 alternative. Look at my edit.

Comment: Thanks. Got it working using advice of Klufy. Upvoted your answer, but I think more cannonical answer is to roll back default Python.